# flex SWFLoader speeding up animation

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am using SWFLoader to load a little animation into my flex environment but for some reason the animation is sped up a lot. This is the case with all of the animations I tried. Is there a way to slow it down or fix this?

Answer (score 1):

i dont think you can slow it down. because it the uses the actual file size as a total length of the swfLoader and the current file that that has been downloaded set as a progress bar.

You can define your own progress bar and use that.